# Seperating C++ Nested Classes into their Own Header Files

Tags: c++, class, c++11, pointers

new to this site and also C++ but hoping to see some guidance from everyone.

I had a pretty fun project idea to learn C++ digging deeper with APIs, classes, references, etc. and currently I have a working example of code where everything exist within the main.cpp file. The issue I am facing is that when i move the classes (inner and outer) to their own respective header files the code no longer compiles.

The reason for the nested classes is that the OuterAPI serves as the main entry point to the API and has many lower level APIs that can be then accessed beneath it (people, licenes, roles, etc). This way users of API would only have to create an object for the OuterAPI and then dot notation for underlying resource and method.

Here is the working example in the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
using json = nlohmann::json;

class OuterAPI {
private:
    class InnerAPI {
    private:
        OuterAPI& api;
    public:
        InnerAPI(OuterAPI& a) :api(a) {}
        json get() {
            cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(
                cpr::Url{ api.baseUrl + "resource" },
                cpr::Bearer{ api.token }
            );
            return json::parse(r.text)
    };

    std::string token;
    std::string baseUrl = "";
public:
    InnerAPI people;
    OuterAPI(std::string t) : token(t), people(*this) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string token = "";
    OuterAPI api(token);
    json jsonData = api.people.get();
    std::cout << jsonData.dump(4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is me moving everything to respective header/cpp files

OuterAPI.h

```
#pragma once

class OuterAPI {
private:
    class InnerAPI;
    std::string token;
    std::string baseUrl = "";
public:
    OuterAPI(std::string t);
    ~OuterAPI();
    InnerAPI* people;
};
```

OuterAPI.cpp

```
#include "WebexAPI.h"
#include "PeopleAPI.h"

OuterAPI::OuterAPI(std::string t) : token(t) {
    people = new InnerAPI(*this);
}

OuterAPI::~OuterAPI() { delete people; }
```

InnerAPI.h

```
#pragma once

#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include "OuterAPI.h"

using json = nlohmann::json;

class OuterAPI::InnerAPI {
private:
    OuterAPI& api;
public:
    InnerAPI(OuterAPI& a);
    json get();
};
```

InnerAPI.cpp

```
#include "InnerAPI.h"

OuterAPI::InnerAPI::InnerAPI(OuterAPI& a) : api(a) {}

json OuterAPI::InnerAPI::get() {
    cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(
        cpr::Url{ api.baseUrl + "resource" },
        cpr::Bearer{ api.token }
    );
    return json::parse(r.text);
```

main.cpp (finally) - this is where the compiler error occurs at `api.people.get()` "`expression must have class type but has type "OuterAPI::InnerAPI *`"

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string token = "";
    OuterAPI api(token);
    json jsonData = api.people.get();     // COMPILER ERROR "expression must have class type but has type "OuterAPI::InnerAPI *"
    std::cout << jsonData.dump(4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

From this I believe the issue is associated with me having to define the `InnerAPI` object `people` as a pointer inside of `OuterAPI` but from here I cant seem to come to a resolution.

Also, feel free to critique my design as well, like I say I am new to C++ so want to make sure I can do a good job. Thanks.

Comment: _"the code no longer compiles."_ When code fails to compile, you are given an error message.  That specific message is important!  It describes the problem that needs to be fixed.  Can you [edit] this question to include the error message that I presume you don't understand?

Comment: `OuterAPI.h` is missing a header guard, and it also has `#include` for headers that it does not use, and is missing the `#include` for things it does use.  (How to organize code is often neglected or glossed over in many C++ books.)

Comment: @DrewDormann, I put the compiler error message in the code snippet for "main.cpp" where it occurs but I can update to be more specific. 

For you though, api.people.get() has the error "expression must have class type but has type "OuterAPI::InnerAPI *"

Comment: @Eljay I did have #pragma once at the top of the header file, just missed it in the code snippet, sorry about that. Good  call on the includes but even moving them around does not seem to change the compiler error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OuterAPI*` you have declared `people` as a member of type `InnerAPI*`.

You can either call your API using `api.people->get()` or make the member a `InnerAPI` instead.

EDIT:

It seems the error, besides the pointer thing, comes from how you handle file includes. I managed to get a [working version on REPL.it](https://replit.com/@Voltra1/Api-Test). I made slight adjustments so I wouldn't have to bring both libraries in so focus on the gist of it. Here it is:

OuterAPI.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>

class OuterAPI {
private:
    class InnerAPI;
    std::string token;
    std::string baseUrl = "";
public:
    OuterAPI(std::string t);
    ~OuterAPI();
    InnerAPI* people;
};
```

InnerAPI.j

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "./OuterAPI.h"

class OuterAPI::InnerAPI {
private:
    OuterAPI& api;
public:
    InnerAPI(OuterAPI& a);
    std::string get();
};
```

OuterAPI.cpp

```cpp
#include "./OuterAPI.h"
#include "./InnerAPI.h"

OuterAPI::OuterAPI(std::string t) : token(t) {
    people = new InnerAPI(*this);
}

OuterAPI::~OuterAPI() { delete people; }
```

InnerAPI.cpp

```
#include "./OuterAPI.h"
#include "./InnerAPI.h"

OuterAPI::InnerAPI::InnerAPI(OuterAPI& a) : api(a) {}

std::string OuterAPI::InnerAPI::get() {
    return api.baseUrl + "resource";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I attempted ```api.people->get()``` but then get the error ```pointer to incomplete class type "OuterAPI::InnerAPI" is not allowed```

Could you elaborate more on "make the member a InnerAPI" would look like as far as implementation? Initially I attempted to define ```people``` without a pointer but got an error as incomplete type.

Comment: You only forward declared it? (e.g.: `class Foo;` is a forward declaration, and `class Foo {};` is a definition.

Comment: Testing things out on the side, I realized the rest of your problem might be how you include files within each other. I added a working draft.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this actually helps me understand now as i did have confusion around the pointer and includes. You helped me identify some areas i must read on more. I appreciate the time you took testing this as well. I tested an was also able to get the code to compile properly. 

If i can ask one more question around includes, for the ```main.cpp``` I had to include both ```Outer.h``` and ```Inner.h``` for this to work. Is there a solution that would allow for only the ```Outer.h``` file to be included in main?

Comment: You can't as you need the definition of `InnerAPI` in order to use it. Since you moved its definition outside of the `OuterAPI` header, you'll have to include it.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a bunch for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include everything you intend to use in every file where you intend to do so.
Separating declaration and definition is pretty common.
It's a way to reduce compile time on large projects.
Thankfully [modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) will soon™ make linking a thing of the past.

To address the error message: you declare `people` as a raw member pointer of the class `OuterAPI`… You cannot access a member through a pointer using `operator .`, you need to use `operator ->`.

Comment: I would like to say thanks to you  ViralTaco_ for your help.